# How do I get a whole list of all available font names on my local computer?

Tags: css, fonts

I am creating a local project so all the fonts I used should be just locally existed. I am using a Mac and I can find them in `/Library/Fonts`. But I guess it's not gonna work if I just put the filename to my CSS property. For example, there is a font named `华文黑体` and if I directly use:

`font-family: "华文黑体"`

it's not working.

How do I know all the names that can be used in a value of CSS property?

Thanks,

Comment: can you open the font('s properties) to maybe find an english name?

Comment: Thanks, click `Get Info` on the context menu and there's a `Fullname` of it. That is exactly what I want. Just wondering is it convenient to bulk display their names. Anyway, helps a lot!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bulk display their names"? Convenient for what? Sorry, just not familiar with the purpose of your project, I think I need a little bit more info to be able to advise on that. (BTW, I'm going to post my first comment as an answer, so other people know the question has a solution.)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably open the font('s properties) to find an english (Latin script) name that will be recognized by CSS.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, could you mark it as correct? If not, please leave a comment as to why it's not sufficient